# Combinational Logic Design, Truth table and K-Map question

Tags: digital-logic

This question is for logic computer designs, I hope it's okay to post it here. It's actually a very simple question I guess.

In this screenshot below, **how did they implement the K-Map from the Truth Table? it's a bit confusing to me, if it was 1 output I would know where to place the 1's on the K-Map.**

[image]

*Note: I found this question on the internet.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a K-map for each one of the outputs.

The first K-map is for the output variable A and the second for B.

You can simply divide your problem in three subproblems, one for each of the outputs.

Comment: my god! I feel so dumb.The solution only has 2 K-Maps so I thought each K-Map for each part. Now it's clear. Thanks so much!